# updating text with jquery in asp.net mvc view

Tags: jquery

I have html like this

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="hidden" class="myID" value="123123123" />
   <div class="firstName"></div>
   <div class="lastName"></div>
   <div class="myImage"></div>
</div>
```

it is repeated over and over

I want to change the value of div with class ".firstName" that follows a specifc hidden field.  I have this value properly stored in a `var` like this

```
var myID = @Model.myID;  //this is from c# mvc, but nevermind that - its value is correct
$('input[value="'+ myID + '"]').next(".firstName").text("mynewvalue");
```

How do I select a hidden input based on it's value with a variable in the selector??  I know that the hidden field is not even being selected , so the code after that - the .next() isnt important , I just need to know how to properly select a hidden field based on its value

I tried

```
$('input[value="myID"]').
$('input[value="'+ myID + '"]')
$('.myID[value="'+ myID + '"]')
$('[value="'+ myID + '"]')
```

**UPDATE**

oh, if I try `$('input[value="123123123"]')`  meaning manually just type a value in there - it works

Comment: Is this after the dom is loaded?

Comment: yes, if i just do $(".firstName")  it will successfully change every one

Comment: `$('input[value='+ myID + ']')` ?

Comment: what is in the variable `myID`?

Comment: @Musa - it is confirmed correct

Comment: do a `console.log(myID);` and re-confirm it.

Comment: and just after, log your `$('input[value="'+ myID + '"]')`

Comment: @Musa - thanks , confirmed in that answers fiddle my selector was fine , its working in his answer , i guess I was wrong when saying it was confirmed correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select hidden fields and you can select them by matching their attributes and values.

jQuery:

```
 $(":input[type='hidden'][value='123']");
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y43A/2/) should get you sorted, of course you'll have to adapt it to your code. Docs on multiple attribute selectors : http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: I put into the question if I just type the value in the selector it works

Comment: that's what I wanted, i'll accept , it looks though that my problem was not in my selector but in the var - as others suggested , you're code is pretty damn close to what  I wrote , but of course- obivously- yours works :)

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/7Y43A/4/ - now it is identical to my code , and works , and least that narrows it a little